# how do I reuse npm's spinner functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to add a spinner to my CLI, but I'm finding it difficult to reuse the spinner that's present in `npm` and is visible when `npm` is making HTTP requests (like in `npm install`).

From what I understand, [this bit of code](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/v1.4.15/lib/npm.js#L167-176) is responsible for making an actual spinner.

Apparently the [char-spinner](https://www.npmjs.org/package/char-spinner) package is used for that and here's its most basic example:

```
var spinner = require("char-spinner")

// All options are optional
// even the options argument itself is optional
spinner()
```

When I run that, however, I don't get anything printed on the screen (`process.stderr`).

What am I doing wrong and what's the right way to reuse the spinner from `npm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spinner will show as long as the process still has something to run and doesn't just exit right away.

Try:

```
var spinner = require( 'char-spinner' );

spinner();

setTimeout( function() {}, 10000 );
```